# Prove if $f$ is a continuous function such that the domain of the function contains a neighborhood...

Tags: real-analysis, limits

i need help with my proof of this exercise

Exercise: Prove if $f$ is a continuous function such that the domain of the function contains a neighbourhood of $L$ and $lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)=L$ then $lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(g(x))=f(L)$

Proof:

As the domain of $f$ contains an Neighbourhood of $L$, then $L$ belongs to the domain of f. $f(L)$ exists because $L$ lies in the domain of $f$, As $f$ is continuous function then  $f(L)=f(lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x))=lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(g(x))$

Is good my proof?

Comment: $f(L)$ exists because $L$ lies in the domain of $f$, not because $f$ is continuous. Yes, your idea about pulling the limit is correct, since $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @TheveryfluffyPanda yeah sorry, i go to write that, but in other words the proof work?

Comment: @TheveryfluffyPanda  now i rewrite my proof.

Comment: You have to more detailed. It does not suffice to argue that $f$ only contains $L$. Why does $f$ contain $g(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$? Well, since it contains a nbhd of $L$, it must contain all elements within a certain distance of $L$.

Comment: Nothing has been made in the proof you presented. You only write the contents of the exercise. That exercise is a standard result in other books. You can google for a while and you will find the proof..

Comment: Continuity has many consequences.Many of these consequences also imply continuity, and therefore are equivalent and can used as equivalent definitions of continuity.What you are trying to prove is one of these.  So you have been asked to show that some other def'n of continuity implies  that f(g(x)) converges to f(L). But we can't answer without knowing the def'n of continuity that you are starting with.